# R combine character vectors into dataframe, with vector name as row id

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have three character vectors:

```
blue <-c("Ti","Ka","Vv","Cn")
Turq <-c("Cc","Wx","Oq","Yt")
Indigo <-c("Gb","Ap")
```

and I want to combine them into one dataframe so that they look like this:

```
blue   Ti
blue   Ka
blue   Vv
blue   Cn
Turq   Cc
Turq   Wx
Turq   Oq
Turq   Yt
Indigo Gb
Indigo Ap
```

I cannot seem to find a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the vectors in a named list and then use `stack`:

```
lst <- list(blue = blue, Turq = Turq, Indigo = Indigo)
lst
# $blue
# [1] "Ti" "Ka" "Vv" "Cn"

# $Turq
# [1] "Cc" "Wx" "Oq" "Yt"

# $Indigo
# [1] "Gb" "Ap"

stack(lst)
#   values    ind
#1      Ti   blue
#2      Ka   blue
#3      Vv   blue
#4      Cn   blue
#5      Cc   Turq
#6      Wx   Turq
#7      Oq   Turq
#8      Yt   Turq
#9      Gb Indigo
#10     Ap Indigo
```

Comment: Or just use `mget` instead of manually naming them as in `stack(mget(ls()))`

Answer (score 0):

This is not very efficient, but it gets the job done.

```
blue <-c("Ti","Ka","Vv","Cn")
Turq <-c("Cc","Wx","Oq","Yt")
Indigo <-c("Gb","Ap")

#assumes no duplicates in the original vectors.
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(blue, Turq, Indigo))

library(tidyr)
df<-unique(gather(df))
```

This will generate a few warnings, but provide your requested result.  cbind with start repeating the vectors so that all of the vectors are the same length.

Comment: `data.frame(cbind(...))` is not a good habit to get into. Why not just `data.frame(blue, Turq, Indigo)` ?

Comment: Nope, no error. And `cbind` will do the same repeating of `Indigo` as `data.frame` will. `identical( data.frame(blue, Turq, Indigo), as.data.frame(cbind(blue, Turq, Indigo)) )`

Comment: Let me rephrase, if the lengths differ and are not multiples of each other then it will throw an error.  Try adding an 5th element to blue and rerun.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df<-data.frame(blue,Turq,Indigo)
library(reshape)
unique(melt(cbind(1:nrow(df),df),id=1)[,-1])

   variable value
1      blue    Ti
2      blue    Ka
3      blue    Vv
4      blue    Cn
5      Turq    Cc
6      Turq    Wx
7      Turq    Oq
8      Turq    Yt
9    Indigo    Gb
10   Indigo    Ap
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt` after placing the vectors in a `list`.

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mget(c("blue", "Turq", "Indigo")))[2:1]
#       L1 value
#1    blue    Ti
#2    blue    Ka
#3    blue    Vv
#4    blue    Cn
#5    Turq    Cc
#6    Turq    Wx
#7    Turq    Oq
#8    Turq    Yt
#9  Indigo    Gb
#10 Indigo    Ap
```